# ipyvolume: clear what is plotted then plot new data?

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter notebook.

I have the following code:

```
import ipyvolume as ipv
import numpy as np
ipv.figure()
VBox([ipv.gcc()])
```

then using the following code I'm plotting:

```
x, y, z, u, v, w = np.random.random((6, 1000))*2-1
quiver = ipv.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, size=5, size_selected=8, selected=selected)
```

If I run the above code multiple times ipv plot will add new points to the current plot.

What I want is to first clear the previous plotted view (without refreshing the cell) then plotting the new data.
sth like:

```
ipv.clear_item(quiver)
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the x data of quiver by running `quiver.x = x_new`, and so on in a different cell.

Answer (score 0):

ipv.clear()

ipyvolume.pylab.clear()

Remove current figure (and container).

[ipyvolume.readthedocs.io](https://ipyvolume.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)